# How to show a div near a button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page which has a lot of buttons. What I need to do is to show a div near the button. I tried this:

```
<style>
#noteDiv {display:none; position: absolute; background-color: white; border: 1px solid blue;}
</style>
<script>
function showNote(e) {

var x = 0, y = 0;
if (!e) e = window.event;

if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
      x = e.pageX;
      y = e.pageY;
                  }
else if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
    x = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    y = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop  + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                 }


document.getElementById("noteDiv").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("noteDiv").style.left = (x)+"px";
document.getElementById("noteDiv").style.top = (y-350)+"px";


                }

function hideNote() {
  document.getElementById("noteDiv").style.display = "none";
 }
</script>

<body>    
<?php
 echo "<button type ='button' id = 'noteButton'>Note</button>"; 
 echo "<script>document.getElementById('noteButton').onclick = showNote;\n";
 echo "</script>";
 ?>
</body>
  <div id='noteDiv'  >
  <div ><span onclick="hideNote()">Close</span></div>
  <br clear="all">
  <div id='noteContent' style='max-height: 30em'></div>
  </div>
```

It does work. But sometimes the page will show one more div on top of the page, like a warning message, and thus the noteDiv's position will be far from the buttons to which it should attach.

My thinking is to get the position of the buttons, and send the x, y values of the button position to the function showNote(), from there show the noteDiv. I don't know if this idea is reasonable and how to get and transfer the current clicked button's position to javascript?

Any suggestions and hints will be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a working example? Something like a jsfiddle that shows the error. Thank you.

Comment: Feels like your design is the primary problem. Instead of approaching the situation by x, y values through CSS attributes, why not use javascript to append the button as a child element of the div you want it to appear beside?

Comment: Also, please consider to dedicate some time on code indentation. It makes it much more readable.

Comment: Thank you guys! There are no error showing. The page works, but the noteDiv is at the lower position on the page. I edited the codes above.

Answer (score 2):

All the HTML like `<button>` `<div>` `<span>` `<ul><li>` `<table>` etc MUST be inside the `<body> </body>` tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <!-- you can include css and javascript here -->
    <!-- but best place to include javascript ist at the bottom -->
    <!-- see last comment -->
</head>
<body>

    <?php echo '<button type="button" id="noteButton">Note</button>';   ?>


    <!-- best place to include javascript or echo them with PHP what ever
     right before the closing body tag -->
</body>
</html>
```

You are `echoing` a `<button>` via PHP before the opening `<body>` tag which is wrong. Try use something like firebug and https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Sorry, it is my fault. The working code is not like that. I edited the codes above.

Comment: @user5004724 there should be absoluetly NOTHING after the closing `</body>` tage except the closing `</html>` tag. NO `<div>` or anything like that

Comment: hi caramba. Thank you for your reply! I added the missing parts, and now it looks better. I tried to focus on the X and Y part and skip them to simplify the question.

Answer (score 2):

From the beginning. 
Load javascript on top of your page is a very **bad idea**. I'll let the tons of web articles to explain you why. Just to say one reason, the js files are downloaded before the html is rendered (depending on the browser), resulting in a slower rendering of the page.

About your approach:

Three words: separation of concerns. Positioning dom elements **is not** what belongs to javascript (except some very rare occasions). 
Styling the *DOM*, which comprehends **positioning of the objects**, belongs to the Cascading Style Sheet, also known as **CSS**.

So if something is not rendered in the right way, don't try to fix it with javascript. It will only drives you to enormous headaches.

For a better answer, please provide a code that can show us the error.

**UPDATE**

Here is a working example (probably not optimised) of what you are maybe trying to achieve. Please, please, please, please... read a book about html, css and js. It's totally worth it. I didn't use *php*, didn't need it.

Just for the records, the general structure of an html page I personally use is like this one:

```
html
    head
        title
        meta
        styles link
        styles sections
        js **LIBRARIES** which need to be loaded on **TOP**
        google analytics
    body
        html content
        js **LIBRARIES** which need to be loaded on **BOTTOM**
        js scripts
```

And for your sanity, and of the people who helps you, **indent correctly** (it's also a sign of respect to the people who are reading your code).

Here is the code with the snippet:

```js
function toggleNote(id) {

  var noteParent = document.getElementById(id);
  var note = noteParent.querySelector('.note');
  var display = "none";
  if (note.style.display == "none" || note.style.display == "" ) {
    display = "block";
  }
  note.style.display = display;
}
```

```css
.note {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.noteContent {
  max-height: 30em
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="buttonContainer" id="note0">
    <button id='noteButton' onclick="toggleNote('note0')">Note</button>
    <div class='note'>
      <div>
        <button onclick="toggleNote('note0')">Close</button>
      </div>
      <br clear="all">
      <div class='noteContent'>It's something!</div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Also, as @caramba suggested, using an Inspector to view the html rendered is a good idea. Try considering the Chrome inspector.

Comment: Thank you Edoardoo! There is no error, but the noteDiv moves because sometimes the page will show a warning message on the top, and everything will be moved down, and the noteDiv loses the right position. Don't know how to show a working example...Even the warning message div's size changes depending on different situation.